# Combine two DataFrames with different dates into one with ascending timeline

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to combine two different `Pandas.DataFrame`s with different dates into one timeseries where each iteraiton in the index is a timestamp from either one of the original `df`s, where the other would then be effectively an `.ffill()` of it's last timestamp.

As a contrived example:

```
df_a = [
   [02-20-2020, 2],
   [02-21-2020, 4],
   [02-23-2020, 6]
]

df_b = [
   [02-20-2020, 3],
   [02-22-2020, 5],
   [02-23-2020, 7]
]
```

The desired result would then be:

```
[02-20-2020, 2, 3],
[02-21-2020, 4, 3],
[02-22-2020, 4, 5],
[02-23-2020, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do an outer join on date, and then ffill the two columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2020-02-20', '2020-02-21', '2020-02-23'], 'val':[2, 4, 6]})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2020-02-20', '2020-02-22', '2020-02-23'], 'val':[3, 5, 7]})

df_c = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on='date', how='outer', suffixes=['_a', '_b'])
df_c = df_c.sort_values('date')
df_c['val_a'] = df_c['val_a'].ffill()
df_c['val_b'] = df_c['val_b'].ffill()
df_c = df_c.set_index('date')
df_c

            val_a  val_b
date                    
2020-02-20    2.0    3.0
2020-02-21    4.0    3.0
2020-02-22    4.0    5.0
2020-02-23    6.0    7.0
```